# How do I create a formula that will return a date where the sum of it and previous dates are greater than some requested number?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Example of Product Data and Inbounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9klwG.jpg)

I have 20 products that I sell that each have some requested amount that people want to buy. I am struggling to figure out a formula by which I could have it return the week where the sum of it and previous weeks is greater than the amount requested, so I know on what week of inbounds the order can be fulfilled.

The example data only shows three columns of dates but in reality there could be up to 20 weeks of inbounds inventory, so it would be potentially a large series of sums before it finds the one greater than the amount requested. In the example image the cells highlighted in green are the correct week for each product that I manually marked.

Thanks for the help, I'm not sure where to even start on this.

Comment: So do you basically need to highlight what cell summed with all the previous cells returns a number greater than the given value?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table start in cell A1 (therefore the cell C2 value is 96), use this formula for your conditional formatting starting from cell C2:

```
=AND(SUM($C2:C2)>=$B2,SUM($B2:B2)-$B2<$B2)
```

Warning: the formula might stop working if the overall structure of the table is changed. For example: if columns with non-numeric data are inserted, the user will need to re-apply the conditional formatting. If said inserted columns will contain numeric value that are not meant to be sum in the formula, it won't suffice anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I don't have time to write a full answer but the below might help. I am sure there is a way to avoid writing multiple `COUNTIFS` with a `SUMPRODUCT` but I haven't got there yet.

```
=SUM(1,
    COUNTIFS($B3,">"&$C3),
    COUNTIFS($B3,">" & SUM($C3:$D3)),
    COUNTIFS($B3,">" & SUM($C3:$E3))
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a model built around your having 20 weeks so that you can have one formula which doesn't require continuous adjustment - it does require one column of helper cells for each week, though:

[image: Screenshot illustrating proposed model]
the helper cells start in column `Y`, where the formula in `Y2` is

```
=SUM($C2:C2)
```

which is then copied to the right as far as column `AR`, and then copied down, one row for each of your products.
With all of the helper cells populated, the [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) in `W2` is

```
=IFNA(INDEX($C$1:$V$1,MATCH(1,N((Y2:AR2-B2)>0),0)),"In the future")
```

which is then copied down, one row for each of your products.